# C++ - sizeof function applied to object class

Tags: c++

I received the following question which was related to `sizeof()` :

```
class C
{
public:
    C();
    virtual ~C();

    unsigned char _member0 s[4];
    static long _member1 d;
}

int main()
{
    C vc;
    cout << sizeof(vc);
}
```

Can someone explain how the `sizeof()` function is evaluated in this case?

Comment: It's implementation-defined, but here it's basically the current fields + vtable pointer + whatever alignment padding is needed.

Comment: The trick is to add vtable pointer but to exclude static member.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/programming-pointers/4027034/Classes-are-structures-and-then-some) a link to an article where Dan Saks discusses the storage layout of classes. Might supplement the answers below.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function, it's operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact answer could vary from compiler to compiler so in strict sense the answer to your question is this is ***Implementation Defined***.
Considering this to be an interview Q(*saw your previous Q*), You should have pointed out the following points:

- A compiler is allowed to add padding bytes to a structure/class,this might add to the size.
- A compiler might add `vptr` to an class instance,this might add to the size.
- The class members will occupy memory.
- `static` members do not contribute towards the size of an class object because they do not belong to an instance of class but to the class.

Comment: Formally, it's **unspecified**, not implementation-defined. Implementation-defined means that the implementation must document what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It gives the size of vc. vc is of class C. Each object of class C contains metadata (pointer to vtable), since C contains virtual methods. In addition, C has a data field (the character array).

Hence the size of vc should be the size of a pointer plus four bytes (plus padding, see comment below, thanks).

d is not component of an object of class C, since it is static, hence it does not count.

So we have:

```
------vc---------             ----vtable for C----           ----statics----
| ptr to vtable | ----------> | pointer to ~C    |           | C::d        |       
|---------------|             | ...              |           | ...         |
| char [4]      |             --------------------           ---------------
-----------------
```